Compared with "will be able to", does the modal "can" sound more like suggesting an available option to someone?
For example, this is a conversation I made up below:
A: I don't know what majors I should choose.
B: Well, Jack says he might visit me after work.
1. If he comes over tomorrow, he can give you some useful advice.
2. If he comes over tomorrow, he'll be able to give you some useful advice.
I think 1 sounds like B is suggesting Jack as an available advice giver to A and A should consider asking him for help.
On the other hand, 2 sounds more straightforward, It sounds like Jack will have the ability to give him some advice if he comes over.
I am not sure if "can" does have this extra meaning compared with "will be able to."
Please share with me your opinions.

Saying that someone 'can do' something is sometimes used to imply a request or command, but I don't think the implication here is strong enough for a difference in meaning.

I don’t think it’s a request or command either. “Can” is more like suggesting something to you, like providing an option for you to consider.

Read books, magazines, online articles, and short stories; this fixation on one specific aspect of grammar is not helping you understand how the English language flows in real life. Watch shows, TV dramas, documentaries in original language and you hear people using different tenses with different nuances within minutes of it being uttered. Absorb it all, stop analysing every detail, let the language sweep over you, and eventually you'll develop a finer, more in-tuned, "sixth sense", an instinct for what sounds natural and what doesn't. Exposure, exposure, exposure.

I just want to know if anyone else feel the same about this topic.

The difference between the two is subtle and in my mind, as a native speaker, could be used interchangeably, however, I've come up with the following differences:

If he comes over tomorrow, he can give you some useful advice.

This conveys that B feels Jack is a useful source of information on this topic. B feels Jack knows what he is talking about and has maybe given advice of this nature before. If A wants advice, Jack can definitely provide it. There is a certainty that goes with the word 'can' in this context.

If he comes over tomorrow, he 'll be able to give you some useful advice.

This one is actually less straightforward to me and feels more noncommittal compared to the simplicity of "can". This conveys that Jack's advice will be there for the taking, if A is interested in pursuing such advice.
Both of these, however, sound unnatural and presumptuous to me. For the record, the following variations sound better:

If he comes over tomorrow, he could give you some useful advice.

This still implies that Jack is a useful source of information, but B doesn't want to be presumptuous that A wants Jack's help, or perhaps that Jack would want to help--that said, the pronunciation, emphasis, and tone of 'could' can swing the meaning in a lot of different ways here.

If he comes over tomorrow, he 'd be able to give you some useful advice.

This variation is even less presumptuous and suggests that A might reach out to Jack for advice tomorrow, if A is feeling up for some advice. Jack would be able to give such advice.

Yes I agree. "can" sounds like this to me:  "Well, he will be a good helper. You can ask for advice from him if you want."
"will be able to" is more like: "He will have the ability to give you some advice provided that he comes over"

OP's query is about the difference between "can" and "will be able to":

I am not sure if "can" does have this extra meaning compared with "will be able to."

Let's look at the various options to show ability:

could: past ability
can: present ability
will be able to: future (or conditional) ability
am/is/are able to: present ability.

While "can" and "will be able to" are sometimes used interchangeably, they convey slightly different meanings.
For instance, in former President Obama's 2008 campaign slogan,  "Yes, we can" would have lost impact if he had said, "Yes, we will be able to."
Examples to show the difference:

1a) He can get a better job. (present ability)
1b) He will be able to get a better job, provided he gains some experience.
2a) We can meet tomorrow. (ability with some certainty)
2b) We will be able to meet tomorrow, if I’m not busy.
3a) I can complete the project in a month. (more committed)
3b) I will be able to complete the project in a month, if I get the time.

The difference is subtle but useful for making the right choice in context.
Note: "am/is/are able to" can often replace "can" in the present without changing the meaning.



B1) If he comes over tomorrow night, he can give you some helpful advice.
B2) If he comes over tomorrow night, he’ll be able to give you some helpful advice.

B2 sounds like Jack will only gain the ability to provide the advice if he comes over tomorrow

I disagree. There is no particular reason to interpret the modal phrases in the above examples in terms of change in capability/expertise (as opposed to possibility of receiving advice), and not just because the sentences say "[can / will be able to] give you some helpful advice" rather than "[can / will be able to] give some helpful advice".
In fact, B2 (specifically being in the future tense), slightly more so than B1 (being in the present tense), emphasises the opportunity for Jack to give the advice (contingent on the event of him going over), whereas B1 conveys general ability and is slightly less definitive about the helpful advice actually being given.

B1 sounds like suggesting that the listener should ask Jack for advice

Neither B1 nor B2 is more suggestive than the other that Jack's advice should be sought.
On the other hand, the following phrasing would be more presumptuous (and suggestive) that the listener wants Jack's advice: "If he comes over tomorrow night, he'd be able to give some helpful advice."
While "could" and "might" can be presumed as suggestive, in idiomatic usage in statements, this is less so with the word "can", where any suggestiveness that is even intended would be merely secondary to its expression of possibility or ability (or perhaps permission). To wit:

You can/could/might ask the manager about getting a discount
You can/could/might call customer service for more help
We can/could take a walk after dinner.

